# TortoiseSVN client asking for Credentials every time

Tags: authentication, tortoisesvn, credentials

I'm using TortoiseSVN as client and it is asking for the credentials for every action. The 'Save Authentication' doesn't help much. How do I make it to not ask for the credentials every time?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue.  I'm not sure why the conflic happens, but if you clear the the Subversion auth cache it'll start working again.

Delete the following folder:
[docs & settings][UserID]\Application Data\Subversion\auth

The \auth folder will get rebuilt the next time you authenticate, and the "Save Authentication" checkbox should start working again.

Answer (score 1):

http://tortoisesvn.net/ssh_howto.html

Read:
SSH key generation and connection check (client)